# Xcode transparent navigation bar background

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using a custom navigation bar in a view, and I want the bar not to be visible (except for the text and the buttons of course). the view is white, therefore the background of the bar needs to be also white or transparent. but no matter, what I try, it is always barely visible:
[image: Navigation Bar]

This is what it looks like(I know you have to look hard, but the bottom line is visible):

[image: Navigation Bar]

if I need to write any code, please use swift

Comment: try this `let bar:UINavigationBar! =  self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        bar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        bar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        bar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.3, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0)`

Comment: How about; if you want the nav bar to be invisible, don't use a nav bar?

Comment: thx Anbu, that worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```